# Remote client access to windows server remote server connected smartcard

Tags: remote-access, smartcard, windows-server

i have the following problem and does not know how to solve it:

I have a windows server running and a smartcard is via an usb-port connected to the windows server. I want to access to the smartcard via a remote client. In detail, i successfully establish a remote connection to the windows server, but when i try to execute commands on the smartcard it does not work.

Some google research says that it wont work because the server does not allow remote clients the access to the smartcard.

Does a work-around exist? Or are the google research results true?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes workaround exists: do not use [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) - use [some other remote access technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) like [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).